# Check if a List already contains an item or not?

Tags: c#, list

I used a struct

```
public struct stuff
{
    public int ID;
    public int quan;
}
```

in `List<stuff> stuff  = new List<stuff>();`

How i can check the list already have a stuff "where ID = 1"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use LINQ very easily

```
bool res = stuff.Any(c => c.ID == 1);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
bool isContains = stuff.Any(x => x.ID == 1);
```

Comment: It returns true when the element is found in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(stuf.Select(x => x.id).Contains(1))
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: doh, that are 2 itarations ... 1 iteration like `stuff.Any(s => s.ID == 1);` would be nicer :)

Comment: @andreas-niedrmair There is only one iterations, but deeper function call overhead