# Check if the same item already exist in List<string>?

Tags: c#, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if a List already contains an item or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276005/check-if-a-list-already-contains-an-item-or-not)

```
for (int i = 0; i < webSites.Count(); i++)
                {
                    string t = webSites[i];

                    webCrawler(t, levels - 1);
                    // csFiles.add
                }
                MessageBox.Show(webSites.Count().ToString());
                return csFiles;
```

Lets say in webSites i have:

www.google.com

www.microsoft.com

Now in the second level lets say www.google.com exist again so this time i dont want to process it to do the recrusive if it will it will do it all over again the same thing. I need somehow to make or check that it will do each link once. How can i check it ?

I dont need to check just if the item already exist in the List i need to check if it was exist already so dont do it again since it will dig the same links again and repeat it self.

Comment: You make a lot of the question sound a lot like you're just wanting to know if the item already exists in the list, not like you're only wanting to process each value once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temporary List and call it, let's say, "temp".  Every iteration of the for loop, see if the string in that position in webSites is already in temp.  If it is, ignore it.  If it isn't, add it to temp and then process it.

EDIT: Apparently this isn't the best approach.

Comment: and yet it is marked as the answer.. :D

Answer (score 8):

Don't use a list for this - use a `Hashset<string>` - this has expected O(1) lookup time instead of O(n) for a list, and really the "set" metaphor fits perfectly:

```
HashSet<string> visitedPages = new HashSet<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < webSites.Count(); i++)
{
    string page = webSites[i];
    if(visitedPages.Add(page)) //returns true if new page was added
    {
        webCrawler(page, levels - 1);
    }
}
```

If you call this method recursively, of course the declaration of the `visitedPages` hash set must be outside of the method, e.g. make it a member variable so that you can maintain the history of visited pages.

Comment: `if(!visitedPages.Contains(page))
    {
        visitedPages.Add(page);` should be changed to `if(visitedPages.Add(page))
    {`

Comment: @TimS.: yes that would be a good refactoring and save one look up - edited that in

Answer (score 4):

[List.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) method is what you need I guess but

List.Contains is O(n) and I would recommend a Hashset instead which has a O(1) lookup..

if your list contains all the entry then you can also use the Distinct() function in Linq which will return you an enumerable with Distinct elements only..

```
webSites.Distinct()
```

Comment: I dont understand the negative votes.. yes I gave a direct answer to his question and then the drawbacks of using the same and an alternative..what more can 1 do.. :/

Comment: People are jealous of your correct answer.

Comment: I guess it's just because even though a lot of the question sounds like he's looking just to see if the string's already in there, he really just wants to make sure the same value doesn't get processed more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Keep visited items in a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Use `Add` when visiting a page and `Contains` when checking if you already have visited the page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you just select distinct list of websites at first place?

```
foreach (var site in webSites.GroupBy(s => s))
{
  webCrawler(t, levels - 1);
  // csFiles.add
}
MessageBox.Show(webSites.Count().ToString());
return csFiles;
```